# How to add an anonymous function in wordpress hooks by removing create_function

Tags: functions

Currently I have the code below which I would like to replace `create_function` with some anonymous function.

How can this be done?

```
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('',  
    'return  register_widget("time_more_on_time_widget");'
));
```

Answer (score 2):

The create_function is already an anonymous function, what/why would you like to change? ([php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php))

Some other way to do something is (although untested):

```
$anon_func = function() {
    return register_widget("time_more_on_time_widget");
}

add_action('widgets_init', $anon_func );
```

Comment: i would like to replace all instances of create_function as its a secuirty concern after php 5